# Magento 2 install package with composer without SSL

Tags: magento2, composer

I am trying to install a package

```
composer config repositories.swissup composer http://swissup.github.io/packages/
```

Which result in this error

```
  Your configuration does not allow connections to http://docs.swissuplabs.co
  m/packages/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http
```

The same if I change the URL to HTTPS. 
Also this Magento installation hast no SSL certricate yet, so maybe its vene that.

So, how can I install it without HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

composer does not allow unsecure connections by default.

```
secure-http#

Defaults to true. If set to true only HTTPS URLs are allowed to be downloaded via Composer. If you really absolutely need HTTP access to something then you can disable it, but using Let's Encrypt to get a free SSL certificate is generally a better alternative.
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http

So if you really need to, add

```
"secure-http": false
```

to the `config` section, but this is not recommended.

Perhaps you can reach out to swissup labs and ask them for an `https` source?